# Navigation in mobile application does not work in kendoui professional 2014.1.528

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I updated to version 2014.1.528 kendoui in my mobile application. When I run and navigates to another view, it is in the newly opened view, I can not click on anything. I see that the div element where the views are added style pointer-events: none; In the old version all is well.

I tried to run the official demo kendo ui mobile and as I click on: Remote view, it does not work. But only downloaded demos. On the http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile-view/index, is well

Comment: Without any code, I'm not sure how we can help you. Can you reproduce your issue in a jsFiddle?

Comment: in http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile-view/index try click to Remote view. And you have blank page with navbar, not http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/content/mobile/view/remoteview.html

Comment: Yikes! You should probably open an issue on GitHub for that.